# AttributeError: 'CalibratedClassifierCV' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm using `sklearn` linear implementation of SVM classifier `LinearSVM`.

I didn't use it directly but I wrap it with `CalibratedClassifierCV` to get the probabilities in the prediction time, like:

```
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
```

After fitting the model, I tried to get the `coef_` to print the Top features, following this post [Visualising Top Features in Linear SVM with Scikit Learn and Matplotlib](https://medium.com/@aneesha/visualising-top-features-in-linear-svm-with-scikit-learn-and-matplotlib-3454ab18a14d), but this I got this error:

```
coef = classifier.coef_.ravel()
AttributeError: 'CalibratedClassifierCV' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

How can I get the `coef` in the case I wrap the classifier with a calibrator?, I'm not totally interested in this way, thus if there is another way to get the features importance, it will be welcomed.

Comment: assign to variable `svm = LinearSVC(random_state=0)` and then use in `CalibratedClassifierCV(svm)` and in `svm.coef_.ravel()`

Comment: I'm interested in the performance of the calibrated model!, I think if I separate them and reference to the `LinearSVM` it won't be the same, no?

Comment: maybe it won't be the same but `CalibratedClassifierCV` doesn't have this method so you can't get it from  `CalibratedClassifierCV`

Comment: Is there another way to achieve that? the importance of the features?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`coef_` is not an attribute of `CalibratedClassifierCV` however, it is an attribute of the `base_estimator` which is a `LinearSVC` in your case. You can access your base estimator via the `calibrated_classifiers_` which is a list of the fitted models (which depends on the number of models you fit based on your `cv` value). I have shown a sample code which you can refer to for your need.

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
iris = datasets.load_iris()
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
model.calibrated_classifiers_

[<sklearn.calibration._CalibratedClassifier at 0x7f15d0c57550>,
 <sklearn.calibration._CalibratedClassifier at 0x7f15d0c57c18>,
 <sklearn.calibration._CalibratedClassifier at 0x7f15d0aec080>]
```

In this case my `cv` is three so I have three models built, so I would simple loop through them and taken an average.

```
coef_avg = 0
for i in model.calibrated_classifiers_:
    coef_avg = coef_avg + i.base_estimator.coef_
coef_avg  = coef_avg/len(model.calibrated_classifiers_)

array([[ 0.16464871,  0.45680981, -0.77801375, -0.4170196 ],
   [ 0.1238834 , -0.89117967,  0.35451826, -0.89231957],
   [-0.83826029, -0.9237139 ,  1.30772955,  1.67592916]])
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* Starting from sklearn version 0.24, [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV) constructor exposes an `ensemble` argument, that, if set to `False` (assuming `cv` is not set to `"prefit"`), makes `CalibratedClassifierCV` expose only one calibrated classifier trained using all training data. This means we no longer need to loop over all `calibrated_classifiers_` at prediction time:

```
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(random_state=0), ensemble=False)
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
model.calibrated_classifiers_

# Returns a list with one element, [<sklearn.calibration._CalibratedClassifier at 0x7f15d0c57550>]
```

(using an example above, given by Parthasarathy)